# Connecting a Long Stem Thermometer to a Raspberry Pi to automate the recording of temperature in an experiment

Tags: networking, hardware

Is there a way to connect and read the output of a long stem thermometer like this one to a raspberry pi?

[image]

Comment: I think you should provide a data sheet, or at list a model number or a link.

Answer (score 1):

It depends largely on what's inside the thermometer, but I'd say that quite likely the answer is no. Probably it contains a custom microcontroller connected to the thermal probe and the LCD screen.

You probably could use the stem and the rest of the thermal sensor and try to interface it directly with your RPi, or use and analog/digital converter and a thermocouple, or a TMP36 sensor, depending on the range of temperatures that you want to measure.

Comment: yes this is also what I am thinking the LCD would be trash. what I am after are the cheap components inside that I can use.